# GSON Android JSON parsning error

Tags: android, asp.net, json, gson

I have one ASP.NET Webservice that i calling from my Android app and getting out a string with this JSON data:

```
{
    "d": [{
        "__type": "Trafikverket_API.Models.Trafiklage",
        "TagGrupp": "44be2cce-3055-4d22-aaf2-00e098b0422e",
        "Fran": "Gävle,Uppsala,Stockholm",
        "Till": "Norrköping,Linköping",
        "TrafikplatsNamn": "Nyköping C",
        "VisaAnkomst": "true",
        "InstalldAnkomst": "false",
        "InstalldAvgang": "false",
        "SparangivelseAvgang": "6",
        "AnmarkningarAvgang": "SJ Regional",
        "AnnonseratTagId": "249",
        "SparangivelseAnkomst": "6",
        "AnmarkningarAnkomst": "SJ Regional",
        "AnnonseradAnkomstTid": "21:50",
        "AnnonseradAvgangTid": "21:53",
        "BeraknadAvgangTid": null,
        "BeraknadAnkomstTid": null,
        "AnnonseradTidpunktAvgang": "2011-10-23T21:53:00+02:00"
    }, {
        "__type": "Trafikverket_API.Models.Trafiklage",
        "TagGrupp": "eae407a9-61ba-43f4-9c53-c666c2a3f117",
        "Fran": "Stockholm,Södertälje",
        "Till": "Norrköping,Linköping",
        "TrafikplatsNamn": "Nyköping C",
        "VisaAnkomst": "true",
        "InstalldAnkomst": "false",
        "InstalldAvgang": "false",
        "SparangivelseAvgang": "6",
        "AnmarkningarAvgang": "SJ Regional",
        "AnnonseratTagId": "251",
        "SparangivelseAnkomst": "6",
        "AnmarkningarAnkomst": "SJ Regional",
        "AnnonseradAnkomstTid": "22:52",
        "AnnonseradAvgangTid": "22:54",
        "BeraknadAvgangTid": null,
        "BeraknadAnkomstTid": null,
        "AnnonseradTidpunktAvgang": "2011-10-23T22:54:00+02:00"
    }, ..... ]
}
```

I have a object called StationInfo that looks like this:

```
public class DataModel 
{
    public Boolean VisaAnkomst;
    public String TagGrupp;
    public String Fran;
    public String Till;
    public String TrafikplatsNamn;
    public Boolean InstalldAnkomst;
    public Boolean InstalldAvgang;
    public String SparangivelseAvgang;
    public String AnmarkningarAvgang;
    public Integer AnnonseratTagId;
    public String SparangivelseAnkomst;
    public String AnmarkningarAnkomst;
    public String AnnonseradAnkomstTid;
    public String AnnonseradAvgangTid;
    public String BeraknadTidpunktAnkomst;
    public String BeraknadTidpunktAvgang;
    public String VerkligAnkomstTid;
    public String VerkligAvgangTid;
    public String BeraknadAvgangTid;
    public String BeraknadAnkomstTid;
    public String AnnonseradTidpunktAvgang;
    public String VerkligTidpunktAnkomst;
}
```

When i running this:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
DataModel[] stationInfos = gson.fromJson(result, DataModel[].class);
```

I getting this exception:

```
com.google.gson.JsonParseException: Expecting object but found array
```

I ges i need some object that match the object "d" but how do i do that?

Comment: try to add new class `class DotNetDataModel { public DataModel[] d; }` and use like this `DotNetDataModel [] resp = gson.fromJson(result, DotNetDataModel.class); DataModel[] stationInfos = resp.d;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using Gson, i would suggest you to implement the in-built JSON classes:

```
JSONObject obj;
try {
    obj = new JSONObject("yourJsonData");
    JSONArray objD = obj.getJSONArray("d");  // getting your "d" array from json data           
    JSONObject subObject;

    for(int i=0; i<objD.length(); i++)
    {
        subObject = objD.getJSONObject(i); // getting one by one objects from Array
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Quest.: "I wana buy a motorcycle, which one i should choose?" ... Ans.: "Don't buy a motorcycle, buy a car..."

Comment: @Selvin Why should go to borrow motorcycle(3rd party API) if you are already having a car(in-built classes).

Comment: maybe he don't wana stuck in traffic jam(binding to specific class without coding)

Answer (score 1):

You need to adapt the structure of your classes that will hold the data to that of the JSON response. Since "d" is the array containing your elements, everything that you declared in your DataModel class needs to be "part of" a List entry of a superordinate class, say a *Response*.

```
public class Response {
  List<DataModel> data;   //with DataModel as defined by you
}
```

Usage:

```
Response result = gson.fromJson(json_responseString, Response.class);
for (Response.DataModel entry: result.data) {
  //do something with each entry
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if "result" is your main json object then for all objects inside json array you have to use loop like below

```
for(int i=0;i<result.getJSONArray("d").length();i++)
        {
            DataModel[] obj=new Gson().fromJson(result.getJSONArray("d").getJSONObject(i).toString(), VteamsListing.class);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your array is inside the "d" variable, you need to extract it first